# What happens to transactions that has the same nonce as another failed transaction?

Tags: web3js

**TLDR;**

This question comprises of two parts.

1. When the `status` field of eth_call `eth_getTransactionReceipt` is `0` (failed), what could this indicate? (assuming there are multiple scenarios)
2. When there are multiple transactions with the same nonce value and one of them *fails (the case described above), what is the state of the other transactions?

---

We have a system where some times a few transactions may have overlapping nonce.

For this case, we built a mechanism that processes the successful transaction and re-submit all other transactions (hopefully with a different nonce this time).

However, we're not sure what how we should handle the status 'failed' in the transactions' receipt.

If one of the many transactions with the same nonce fails, what happens with the other transactions?

We could imagine a few outcomes:

1. The other transactions are processed as usually having disregarded the failed transaction. (and if one of those fails, the same process is applied until all of them fails or one of them succeeds)
2. The rest of the transactions are also disregarded (perhaps also with the same 'failed' status?)

These are all what we imagine things to be but we cannot find any documentation that describes this case.

It would be great if someone (even without a specific answer to the question) could point us in the right direction.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three stages of a tx lifecycle:

1. Submitting transaction
2. Transaction in mempool
3. Transaction included into the block (is mined)

It is essential to know that it **doesn't matter** if the transaction has **failed** or **succeeded** - in both states - the transaction is included in the block.

- if you send a transaction with lower or equal `nonce` as the latest already mined, you'll get the exception `nonce too low` and it won't be included in the mempool
- if you send a transaction with a greater `nonce` (could be `+1`, `+2`, etc...) the transaction is included into the mempool. To note - the transaction with the same, lower, or greater `nonce` can be already present in the mempool
- the miner/validator picks the next transaction from mempool which is `+1` and includes into the block. If there are multiple transactions with the same `nonce`, that one with a higher gas price is prioritized
- when a transaction is mined, other transactions with the same `nonce` will be dropped from the mempool.

---

There is also the 4. case:

- The transaction is included in the block, but the block gets reorganized and removed from blockchain. This happens not often, but you have to handle this and wait for N confirmations (other blocks) to be sure it won't be dropped.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question is not really answered though.
I'd like to know what happens when a transactions receives a 'failed' status in receipt and at what timing this happens.

For example, is a 'failed' transaction dropped from the mempool?
Or is is considered 'mined', in case all other transactions are dropped?

I'd like to know about the failed case, not the successful one.

Comment: Your question is not correct. The status `failed` or `success` has nothing to do with the `nonce`. `Fail/Success` is completely different as `Mined/Dropped`

Comment: With other words, if transaction is mined - means it was successfully included into the block, the status of the receipt doesn't matter if it was executed successfully or has failed. Nonce belongs to the mining stage, not the executing.

Comment: I was able to understand your answer after reading it a couple of times. Many thanks